# Change ISO ALPHA-2 Country Codes to ISO ALPHA-3 using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, country-codes, vba

I have an Excel file where I have the 2-letter country codes in a column. I would like to be able to run a macro to safely convert all of them into their respective 3-letter codes, with a single pass.

When using normal find and replace in Excel, you can easily run into problems like this...

AT --> AUT

AU --> AUS

but now AUT --> AUST (which is not the result I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

A simple VLOOKUP would seem easiest but if required often then maybe append a space to the end of the 2-letter codes then replace three characters for three characters. There could be problems if your column contains more than just 2-letter codes at present but you have given no hint that such is the case.